# Executing Multiple Statements From Multiple Databases

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

**DB 1:**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $dbname = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $name = "one";

    $db_one = new mysqli($servername, $dbname, $dbpassword, $name);

    if ($db_one->connect_error) {
        die("We are likely experiencing a heavy traffic load, please come back later!");
    }
    ?>
```

**DB 2:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$name = "two";

$db_one = new two($servername, $dbname, $dbpassword, $name);

if ($db_one->connect_error) {
    die("We are likely experiencing a heavy traffic load, please come back later!");
}
?>
```

**My Attempted  Code:**

```
<?php require("db.php"); ?>

<?php //Select All Orders
$stmt = $db_one->prepare("SELECT * FROM `one`");
$stmt = $db_one->prepare("SELECT * FROM `one_table2`");
$stmt = $db_two->prepare("SELECT * FROM `two`");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $one[] = "<tr><td>".$row["fromdbone"]."</td>";
    echo $two[] = "<td>".$row["fromdbtwo"]."</td>";
    echo $three[] = "<td>".$row["fromdbone_table2"]."</td></tr>";
  }
}
$stmt->close();
?>
```

Hey everyone I am at a loss here, how exactly would I go about executing multiple querys from different tables and databases in order to put it all into one table?

Thanks so much for your insight I trust you are all a lot smarter than me!

EDIT: Or if I was to do multipe querys, how would I get them all into one HTML table?

Thanks, I have been trying to figure this out for hours so I hope you can help!

Comment: What is `$db_bans`? The scripts set `$db_one` and `$db_two`.

Comment: You need to assign each prepared statement to a differnt variable. Otherwise you're only executing the last query.

Comment: But you probably should be joining the tables in a single query. It's hard to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar I edited it now sorry, I took this code from my already working system and changed it to make an example

Comment: You don't need to use different connections for each database. You can access a table in a different database by using a prefix: `SELECT * FROM two.two`

Comment: I have multiple tables and databases, and I want to join them all into 1 table, the best way to do this is within one while loop, how do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: How are the tables related to each other? Is there a foreign key relationship?

Comment: There is a unique key between all of them so I know which user links to what, at the moment I am displaying each set of information in multiple HTML tables. Where I want to combine them all into one table.

Comment: What is wrong with my "Attempted Code", how do I make it execute  all of these querys and then have them all in one while statement?

Comment: You need to assign each statement to a different variable. The 2nd and 3rd would have to have a `WHERE` that selects the row with the same id as from the first table, and you'll have to bind the parameter from the result of the first query so you get the related rows from the other tables.

Comment: @Barmar Would you be willing to show me how I would do that in an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the two databases are on the same server (localhost), you don't need to use different connections for them. Use a single connection, and join all the tables. The table that isn't in the default database can be accessed using the database prefix.

```
$stmt = $db_one->prepare("SELECT * FROM one AS o
    JOIN one_table2 AS o2 ON o.id = o2.one_id
    JOIN two.two AS t ON o.id = t.one_id");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $one[] = "<tr><td>".$row["fromdbone"]."</td>";
    echo $two[] = "<td>".$row["fromdbtwo"]."</td>";
    echo $three[] = "<td>".$row["fromdbone_table2"]."</td></tr>";
  }
}
$stmt->close();
```

To do it with multiple statements, you need to bind parameters.

```
$stmt1 = $db_one->prepare("SELECT * FROM `one`");
$stmt2 = $db_one->prepare("SELECT * FROM `one_table2` WHERE one_id = ?");
$stmt3 = $db_two->prepare("SELECT * FROM `two` WHERE one_id = ?");

$stmt2->bind_param("i", $one_id);
$stmt3->bind_param("i", $one_id);

$stmt1->execute();
$result1 = $stmt1->get_result();
while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
    $one_id = $row['id'];
    $stmt2->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
    $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    $stmt3->execute();
    $result3 = $stmt3->get_result();
    $row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc();
    echo $one[] = "<tr><td>".$row1["fromdbone"]."</td>";
    echo $two[] = "<td>".$row2["fromdbtwo"]."</td>";
    echo $three[] = "<td>".$row3["fromdbone_table2"]."</td></tr>";
}
$stmt1->close();
$stmt2->close();
$stmt3->close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I hate doing this due to readability issues for me, how can I have multiple statements and then echo the results like in my example above? Thanks :)

Comment: OK, I've added that version.